# Не подтягивать foreign key поля

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest

Пробую переписать Java EE проект в C#. 
Замапил базу с помощью Entity Framework, создались классы под каждую таблицу.
Везде где есть foreign key фреймворк так же подтянул соответствующую сущность, например:

```
namespace MainProject.Model.Entity
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AcOpTabl
    {
        public Nullable<decimal> WaveLeng { get; set; }
        public string Nzv { get; set; }
        public string Uzv { get; set; }
        public string Nsv { get; set; }
        public string E { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> M1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> M2 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> M3 { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }


        public virtual HeadTabl HeadTabl { get; set; }
        public virtual Bibliogr Bibliogr { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь получить записи бд из контроллера для этой сущности, но запрос выполняется бесконечно долго. подозреваю, что дело в подтянутых сущностях по внешнему ключу и при сериализации в json попадает в бесконечный цикл...

```
namespace MainProject.Controller
{
    public class AcOpTablsController : ApiController
    {
        private CrystalEntities db = new CrystalEntities();

        // GET: api/AcOpTabls
        public IQueryable<AcOpTabl> GetAcOpTabl()
        {
            return db.AcOpTabl;
        }

        // GET: api/AcOpTabls/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(AcOpTabl))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAcOpTabl(int id)
        {
            AcOpTabl acOpTabl = db.AcOpTabl.Find(id);
            if (acOpTabl == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(acOpTabl);
        }

        // PUT: api/AcOpTabls/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult PutAcOpTabl(int id, AcOpTabl acOpTabl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != acOpTabl.ID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(acOpTabl).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!AcOpTablExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/AcOpTabls
        [ResponseType(typeof(AcOpTabl))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostAcOpTabl(AcOpTabl acOpTabl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.AcOpTabl.Add(acOpTabl);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = acOpTabl.ID }, acOpTabl);
        }

        // DELETE: api/AcOpTabls/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(AcOpTabl))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteAcOpTabl(int id)
        {
            AcOpTabl acOpTabl = db.AcOpTabl.Find(id);
            if (acOpTabl == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.AcOpTabl.Remove(acOpTabl);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(acOpTabl);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool AcOpTablExists(int id)
        {
            return db.AcOpTabl.Count(e => e.ID == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Если у таблицы нету внешних ключей запрос отрабатывает нормально. Как можно исправить это? В java я мог просто пометить поле класса несериализуемым и все работало как надо, как сделать так же в C#?

**EDIT 1**

Запрос оказывается тянет все связанные сущности, даже если нету внешнего ключа. Если другая таблица ссылается на значение в запрашиваемой таблице, то почему-то возвращает все ссылающиеся таблицы + значение из текущей.

Comment: Попробуйте отключить ленивую загрузку: `db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` Это можно сделать и в самом классе `CrystalEntities`. Ещё вариант: убрать модификатор `virtual` у свойств связанных сущностей.

Comment: На вашем месте я бы маппил `EF` сущности на их вью модели и парсил эти модели непосредственно...

Answer (score 3):

Загрузка связанных данных в EF [бывает](https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level3/3_4.php) трёх видов:

- Отложенная загрузка (lazy loading)
- Прямая загрузка данных (eager loading)
- Явная загрузка (explicit loading)

По умолчанию в EF включена ленивая загрузка, я обычно сразу отключаю её -  сразу на уровне всего контекста:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext()
        : base("name=Asdf")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Somethig> Somethig{ get; set; }
    ...
```