# Visual Studio is busy asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

При добавлении записи в бд, из контролера возвращается PartialView, который должен просто выводить все объекты в html-список.

Но, если в таблице только 0 или 1 запись(если больше, то работает нормально), студия зависает с таким сообщением:

"Microsoft Visual Studio is busy."

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ладно бы это была ошибка, можно как то отладить, но пол дня потрачено только на поиски причин...

Модели:

```
public class Basket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public int? ProductId { get; set; }       
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }       
}


public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }              
}
```

Контроллер:

```
  public ActionResult AddProduct(int productId, int  count)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid )
            {
                var basket = new Basket();
                //....

                db.Baskets.Add(basket);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return PartialView(db.Baskets);
            }
        }
```

И после записи в бд, возвращаеться такое PartialView

```
 @model IEnumerable<ShopStore.Models.Basket>
        
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li><a href="#">@item.Product.Title</a></li>
    }
```

Ошибка тут: **item.Product.Title**, если написать **item.Id**, то все работает хорошо, то есть ошибка похоже именно в загрузке Product, но что происходит "за кулисами" мне пока не известно. И снова же, почему при двух и более записях все работает....

Спасибо!

Comment: Нужен минимально необходимый пример для воспроизведения проблемы, тот код, который у вас представлен в вопросе -- вполне нормальный код, нечему там сбоить. Но насколько я понимаю, вы в представлении не отцепились от базы и продолжаете подтягивать данные. Попробуйте [отключить lazy load](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/675364/213987) и явно забирать данные. А в [аналогичном вопросе на en-so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37862214/5752652) вообще говорят о том, что причин у проблемы может быть много: кому-то помогает папку почистить, кто-то ковыряет глубоко proc mon'ом...

Comment: @A K , да чистил и тд, но конкретно тут проблема именно в этой строке. Добавил контроллер.  Думаю отключение lazy load  поможет, но хотелось именно так сделать

Comment: Используйте вместо модели не `db.Baskets`, а `db.Baskets.Include(x => x.Product).ToArray()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, [ещё раз повторю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/675364/213987):

Загрузка связанных данных в EF [бывает](https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level3/3_4.php) трёх видов:

- Отложенная загрузка (lazy loading)
- Прямая загрузка данных (eager loading)
- Явная загрузка (explicit loading)

Во-вторых, попробуем описать механику.
Когда вы пишете запрос как db.Baskets у вас на сервер уйдёт один SQL-запрос вида `SELECT * FROM basket`. И всё. Допустим, этот одиночный запрос вернёт "всего лишь" 800 строк.

А когда вы дойдёте до выполнения view вы в цикле создадите ещё 800 запросов, но уже к таблице продуктов. Что-то вида `SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = 1` (потом 2, 3 и так восемьсот раз). На небыстром ноутбуке можно увидеть хорошее слайдшоу и тормоза.

Я же в своём запросе попросил сразу подтянуть таблицу продуктов -- поэтому у меня SQL-запрос выполняется всего 1 раз, а не 801 раз.

```
var model = db.Baskets
    .Include(x => x.Product)
    .ToArray();
```

Запрос SQL мой будет примерно такого вида:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1], 
    FROM  [dbo].[Baskets] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[???] = [Extent2].[???]
```

Ничего сверхъестественного, всего лишь один JOIN.

Механика понятна?

В-третьих, если вы отключите lazy loading вы (помимо того, что увидите кучу ошибок на своём проекте) сразу научитесь думать, какие запросы делает компьютер, насколько они оптимальны. Сейчас наверное выгоды от этого режима вам сложно оценить, но это очень хорошая практика.