# Переделать данный запрос SQL на Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq2sql

```sql
SELECT
  Расходные_материалы.Код_расходного_материала
FROM Оборудование_на_рабочем_месте
INNER JOIN Оборудование ON Оборудование_на_рабочем_месте.Код_оборудования = Оборудование.Код_оборудования
INNER JOIN Модель ON Оборудование.Код_модели = Модель.Код_модели
INNER JOIN Модель_Расходник ON Модель.Код_модели = Модель_Расходник.Код_модели
INNER JOIN Расходные_материалы ON Модель_Расходник.Код_расходника = Расходные_материалы.Код_расходного_материала
WHERE Оборудование_на_рабочем_месте.Код_рабочего_места = 5
```

Comment: Вы ранее работали с EF, linq? С чём конкретно у вас затруднения? Пользовались Code First или Database First?

Comment: В пособии "метанит" это называлось "код сэконд"

Comment: затруднения с синтаксисом linq. раньше не работал.

Comment: Вот [ваш вопрос, только в обратной форме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/681279/213987): сначала был написал linq, а потом показано как он разворачивается в INNER JOIN. Ну и таблиц у вас несколько поэтому несколько .Include().Include() будет в цепочке.

Comment: 'var model = db.Baskets
    .Include(x => x.Product)
    .ToArray();

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1], 
    FROM  [dbo].[Baskets] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[???] = [Extent2].[???]'  ,Баскет у вас в коде это фром, а х.продакт  код продукта? Если и так, то больше я не  понял(

Comment: <зануда>не используйте в качестве имени таблиц/полей/идентификаторов русские названия, как минимум это неудобно при написании запросов/кода из за постоянного переключения раскладки клавиатуры, если есть проблемы со знанием языка то можно воспользоваться [переводчиком](https://translate.google.com/)</зануда>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как мне кажется небольшой пример не помешает:

```
from e in equipments
//делаем соединение с таблицей справочником "Типы оборудвание"
join equipmentType on e.TypeId equals equipmentType.Id
// фильтруем оборудование по типу
where e.TypeId = 1
// Создаем новый анонимный класс в который будет спроецирована наша выборка
//Имя поля = значение поля
select new
{
    Id = e.Id,
    Type = equipmentType.Id
}
```

данный *запрос* Вы можете присвоить какой либо переменной и *материлизовать* его, например при помощи метода `ToList()`, после которого будет осуществлен запрос на сервер и получение результатов.

В принципе данный синтаксис как мне кажется очень похож на `sql` поэтому особых проблем быть не должно.

*тоже самое* в лямбда синтаксисе

```
equipments
    .Where(x=>x.TypeId == 5)
    .Include(x=>x.EquipmentType)
    .Select(x=> new
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Type = x.EquipmentType.Name
    });
```

**P.S.:** у данного примера есть одно ограничение в модели должны быть созданы *навигационные* свойства, первый же пример не накладывает никаких ограничений

**P.S.S.**

Раз уж Вы упомянули *metanit*, то тогда рекомендую почитать для большего понимания: [Linq](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.1.php), в свое время тоже начинал с данного ресурса.

Comment: да, с примером, определённо лучше. просто спасибо, ибо рейтинг не позволяет